# How to perform a post action when a python subprocess is complete

Tags: python, elasticsearch, subprocess, logstash

I have a python script that creates a subprocess to run indexing operations (logstash to elasticsearch).

the code snippet is as follows,

```
process = subprocess.Popen([logstash, '-f', sample.conf],
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I do not call process.wait(), as the subprocess I'm creating needs to run independent of the rest of the script.

But I do have to update the database record when the subprocess is complete. The indexing operation that I am running does not allow me to create a post job call that will allow me to update the database.

How can I handle this with python subprocess? I do store the PIDs of the jobs in a text file, but I'd like to have a trigger in place that knows when the subprocess is complete to execute the next script.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your process in a thread. You can `wait` from the thread, so you get the output, and it's non-blocking

```
import threading
import subprocess

def run_command():
    p = subprocess.Popen([logstash, '-f', sample.conf],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = p.stdout.read()
    p.wait()
    # now your command has ended, do whatever you like
```

and in your main thread:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=run_command)
t.start()
# continue with main processing
```

Comment: this looks like the write approach to me. but executing the above code throws an error "TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable". It looks like creating a subprocess inside a subprocess is not allowed. Have you successfully tested the above code?

Comment: sorry, typo! fixed. I haven't tested that, but it's very similar to things I have written, which works.

Comment: Thanks, the errors did disappear. However if I execute the above code, once the main thread code is complete the script hangs on the terminal until the subprocess is complete. How do I let the subprocess run and exit the main thread (as in make the command line active again)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to stash the `process` variable somewhere, later you can check its [`returncode` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) after calling its `poll` method.

If the process has completed then its `returncode` value won't be `None` and you can update your database.

Comment: this is similar to what I have mentioned in my post, I store the PID in a text file with which I can check whether the subprocess is complete or not. checking the returncode will have to be done by executing another script later which is not I intend to do. I want to post action to be automated (should run as soon as the subprocess is complete).

Comment: Are you saying you want your program to start a number of processes and then terminate? And that you want to run a database update after each subprocess terminates? Where do you imagine (i.e. in what process context) that the post-completion code would run?

Comment: That's right, the main python script executes the indexing operations as subprocesses. "Where do you imagine (i.e. in what process context) that the post-completion code would run?" this is exactly where I'm stuck. The subprocess calls a certain program/file that cannot be modified, hence I cannot include the post-completion script to update the db there. I was hoping if the subprocess would have a callback, perhaps there is a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Callbacks are no use unless the callback and the code performing the callback run in the same process. Your only hope is to define a shell script that runs the logstash and then performs a database update command that only runs on successful completion. Something like `logstash -f sample.conf && update-the-database`